# Graph api stream_post does not return false

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
foreach($ret_obj as $person)
{        
    $a = $person['uid'];
    echo $a.'<br />';
    $page_feed = $facebook->api(
        '/'.$a.'/feed',
        'POST',
        array(
            'message' => 'Message',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'description' => 'description',
            'link' => ''.FB_BASE_URL.'',
            'picture' => 'http://link.edu/pic.jpg',
            'access_token' => ''.$fbme[access_token].'' 
        )
    );

    //if $page_feed is defined it prints yes if not defined prints no
    if($page_feed){echo 'yes<br />';}
    elseif(!$page_feed[id]){echo 'no<br />';} 
}
```

Somebody do not open their wall even to their friends. Then I want to check that if `$page_feed` is true or false. I am trying to do this in last two rows. I have tried with `isset()`. Whatever I did I couldn't print `no`.

When it posts, `$page_feed` variable returns something like this: `533444332_475819545445666`
 and I tried code below but it give me a blank page again.

```
if($page_feed){echo strstr($page_feed[id],'_').'<br />';}
elseif(strstr($page_feed[id],'_')){echo 'no<br />';}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current user is not allowed to post on someone else’s wall, then trying to do so will result in an exception – so you have to use

```
try { … } catch(FacebookApiException $e) { … }
```

to properly react to that, otherwise your script will just die cause of the uncaught exception.

> Somebody do not open their wall even to their friends.

If it’s only friends of the current user you are trying to post to, then probably it’d be better to check upfront if they allow that.

You can use FQL to do that – the `user` table has a field called `can_post` – *“Whether or not the viewer can post to the user's Wall.”*

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN
  (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me())
  AND can_post
```

This query will give you only those friend’s ids that allow your current user to post to their walls. Intersect that with the list of user ids you are trying to post to – and you won’t have to make fruitless attempts at posting that are bound to fail, which after all will still cost time for the HTTP request.

(You should of course catch possible API exceptions nevertheless, because there’s always other things that might go wrong, and you don’t want your script to just die in those cases either.)